# Local Django server cannot connect when run through Bash on Windows

Tags: python, linux, django, windows, bash

I recently realized that I could use Bash for Windows as the terminal for use in Pycharm so that the IDE had a proper terminal in it even through it was in Windows. I want to work on a Django project but I realized something strange. When I run the server through the IDE's run button, everything runs as expected. However, when I try to run the server through the command line via

`python3 manage.py runserver`,

the terminal output is the same, but my browsers cannot connect. Instead they say that the connection was reset. I have full installations of Django and Python for both Windows and the Bash environment and both seem to be fully functional. I can make migrations and create new apps through the command line just fine, but I was wondering if anybody else knew why the Django Server does not connect when run through Bash on Windows

Comment: Can you provide your browser error pic ?

Comment: It might be bug in the Bash for Windows, since it is in beta

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the browser error
http://j43i.imgup.net/Djangoerrofd28.JPG

Comment: Same problem here.